# When I load a new view in Cocoa Touch, it shifts everything up about 20 pixels

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

[image]

Ok so as seen in this picture progression, I have a home screen with a button named "Songs" on it.  When this is pressed, it loads a new Nib and .h and .m files as seen in the middle picture.  Then the back button brings us back to the home menu.

The problem is when I load that new view it shifts everything up 20 pixels (around how much the status bars are).  Does anyone have any idea why this is.  Let me know.  I can provide code too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this problem before.  The only way I could remedy it was to set each new view I created to the size of the screen.  Here's how I did it:

```
CGRect fullFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
self.view.frame  = fullFrame;
```

Comment: Does anyone know the problem this solution is fixing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that `wantsFullScreenLayout` is set to `YES` somewhere. Check your `UIViewController`s.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably adding the view to the window with the frame (0,0, 320,460). So add 20 pixels to the y coordinate. The better choice would be using  the UIViewController instead.

Comment: Yup. 20 pixels is the height of the status bar, you're probably not taking that into account.

Comment: actually i take. You should use UINavigationController to push/pop your views. Then you don't have any problems with the status bar.

Comment: I've had this issue before. Please see my response below.